# Google script create new spreadsheet and set as active

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can create a new spreadsheet using:

`var newWorksheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("newWorksheetName");`

However, how do I immediately set it as active so I can edit it?

As far as I know, I need to get the spreadsheet ID, to open it, but I don't know how to find this out automatically.

Comment: Hi Phil. I posted my answer. Let me know if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var crNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("newWorksheetName");
var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(crNew.getUrl());
```

where `ssNew` is the new Spreadsheet file.

Then you can use **ssNew** to directly access the new Spreadsheet file.
For example, the following will give you the name of the first sheet of the newly generated **newWorksheetName**:

```
Logger.log(ssNew.getSheets()[0].getName());
```

Output: `Sheet1`

Another example would be to change the name of the sheet:

```
ssNew.getSheets()[0].setName("newname");
```

Comment: Thanks, but `sh` returns the current worksheet where the script is, not the new one that has just been created.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? you can directly access the new sheet using its name (ssNew). For example: ssNew.getRange("A1").setValue("this is the active sheet"). See my edited answer for more details.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new *worksheet* (spreadsheet file), into which I am going to populate data. It's not a new *sheet* (tab) inside the existing worksheet. `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` always returns the current open spreadsheet, which is the master, rather than the new spreadsheet I create with `SpreadsheetApp.create("newWorksheetName")` Google's product names need work!

Comment: Easy mistake, I have updated my question to be clearer.

Comment: @PhilPenny check my new edited answer. Essentially, you create a new spreadsheet file, then you get it by using its URL. ssNew can then be used directly to perform any actions on it.

Comment: @PhilPenny please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Comment: This is returning the correct info to the logger, but it won't update the spreadsheet. For example, if I run `ssNew.getSheets()[0].setName("Phil");` the logger correctly prints out "Phil" but the spreadsheet itself remains with it's sheet title as "Sheet 1"

Comment: This is not what I am getting. See my edited answer